# Is it possible to use the hash (#, pound) key in a key binding in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

On UK keyboards, the hash symbol (#, a.k.a pound elsewhere) has its own key (with tilde above it).

Presumably because it is not a standard key on US keyboards, it isn't listed in the [list of named keys in the documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) for use in custom keystrokes.

Is there a way to reference it when creating custom key bindings?

Comment: Bit late, but entering `sublime.log_input(True)` in the Sublime console and then pressing the key will tell you what Sublime sees it as. You can then use that key in your binding.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks, that is useful to know about.  The console gives me `chr evt: # (0x23)`.  It turns out that I can bind either `#` or `~` to commands, but not more useful combinations like `ctrl+#` or `alt+#`.  I don't suppose there is a way of using the `0x23` code?  I couldn't see anything referenced this way in the default keymap.

Comment: You can only use the character/name, not the hex code. What do you see as the output in the log when you press `ctrl+#` and `alt+#`? Possibly with a different keyboard layout the key represents as something different when used with modifiers.

Comment: @OdatNurd Good idea, odd results.  `#` combinations come up as though they were combined with `'` (apostrophe) instead, e.g. `key evt: shift+control+'`, except for `ctrl+#` which registers as both `key evt: control+'` and then `chr evt:  (0x1c)`.  All combinations with the actual apostrophe key come out as though they were combined with backtick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that this is possible, but the binding that you need might not be what you expect it to be due to your keyboard layout and/or a bit of a logical "hiccough" you might not expect in the way that Sublime maps keys.

Explaining the reason for that and how you determine what your binding needs to look like for that (or any other) key is a bit more involved though.

Generally speaking, Sublime uses scan codes in order to determine what key you're pressing. Scancodes are based on the position of the key on the keyboard and not on the characters that they actually create.

The upshot of this is that Sublime sees keys that you press as if they were on a US keyboard even if they're not; the list of keys in the list you mention in your question assumes a standard US keyboard layout.

In order to diagnose key binding problems or see how Sublime is reading your input, you can turn on input logging by opening the Sublime console with `View > Show Console` from the menu and entering the following command:

```python
sublime.log_input(True)
```

While input logging is turned on, Sublime will report a message in the console regarding every input event that it's seeing. Input logging remains in effect until you run the same command with `False` or restart Sublime.

You're generally going to see one of the following:

- `chr evt: #`, which tells you that you pressed a *character*
- `key evt: backspace`, which tells you that you pressed a *key*
- `key evt` followed by `chr evt`, which means that the key you pressed is something akin to a *dead key* that is trying to add a diacritic to a character.
- nothing at all if the key is truly dead or something outside of Sublime (e.g. the OS) ate the keyboard event before Sublime got a chance to see it

To bind a key to something that's reporting a `chr` event, your mapping should include just the character:

```
{ "keys": ["#"], "command": "echo"},
```

To bind a key that is reporting as a `key` event, you would use the key as it's reported in the event, including any modifiers (`control` works as well as `ctrl`):

```
{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "echo"},
```

With all of that said, what the input logging reports might not always be what you would initially expect it to be, which is one of the items mentioned in the comments on your original question.

Key combinations that generate characters are reported as `chr` events, which means they take the shift state into account. Keys that don't generate a character are reported as `key` events, and include the modifier and the ***key that was pressed***.

That bit is emphasized because it might not be what you initially expect.

By way of example, on a US keyboard layout, `#` and `3` share a key, with `#` being the shifted version of the key.

Thus:

- <kbd>3</kbd>: `chr evt: 3 (0x33)`
- <kbd>shift+3</kbd>: `chr evt: # (0x23)`

This makes logical sense; pressing the `3` key alone gets you a literal `3`, while using shift gets you a hash character.

However, note the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd>: `key evt: control+3`
- <kbd>Ctrl+#</kbd>: `key evt: control+3`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+3</kbd>: `shift+control+3`

That is; in order to get the `#` character I need to press shift, but the key event reported is for the `3` key, because that's really the key I'm pressing.